# Python and PyDev unused imports - possible to disable on the package level?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have a project where I use south migrations. Often, the migrations .py file has unused imports. This generates warnings in PyDev/Eclipse. I want the warnings turned on in general, as they promote code discipline. However, I wish I could either turn them off on the package in Eclipse or through some directive.

I am aware of the #@UnusedImport comment tag. Is it possible to do something like that, but on a package level? Perhaps **init**.py could be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `# @PydevCodeAnalysisIgnore` at the top of the module will cause PyDev to skip all code analysis on a given file. While not quite on  package level, this is good enough.